# Good language & framework for cross platform (windows & mac) desktop application

Tags: cross-platform, desktop-application

The last cross platform desktop development I did was Java/Swing.  What about flex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do it. If you need to go cross-platform, write the main guts of your application in a business logic layer that doesn't depend on any GUI framework and then use the native platform API to finish each app.

Your users will thank you.

Comment: I agree with Jim here. We currently use Qt for cross platform development. The framework is great but there is still some limitation to it. At some points you will have to put ifdefs for various platforms and if you use openGL in your application it gets more complicated.

Answer (score 4):

I'd choose an open alternative and I'd try to avoid vendor lock-in.
As Richard said, "if you've mastered Java/Swing why not use it again?"

Answer (score 3):

I've used [RealBasic from RealSoftware](http://www.realsoftware.com/products/realbasic/) for a few things just to play with it.  It can get expensive if you need the pro version.  It will allow you to build a stand alone binary for Linux, MacOS X, or Windows.  I'm more of a server side guy but it was pretty straight forward to create the few tools I wanted to try making with it.

Answer (score 3):

[Qt](http://www.trolltech.com/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm a big fan of [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/).  My only experience with it is with C++.

Comment: There is also a very nice Python binding called wxPython as well.

Answer (score 2):

A combination of Python, [wxPython](http://wxpython.org/), [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) and [py2app](http://undefined.org/python/py2app.html) is what I typically fall back on. I've recently had a run with AIR, and it isn't that bad.. so Flex might work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Flex/AIR is a platform with a lot of potential.
It's also a lot prettier than anything Java or .NET.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use Tcl/Tk because it is remarkably powerful and because deployment is a non-issue (with starkits and starpacks you can wrap all program resources -- images, sounds, dll/.so files, etc -- into a single executable file).

Tcl's not for everyone though -- some people find its simplicity a little hard to grok.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore Flex it's not programming IMO. If you can code Java I'm pretty certain that FLex will be a disappointment. Flex has a place, I don't really consider it a proper programming environment.

If you've mastered Java/Swing why not use it again? I would.

.NET can be portable - but IME it's not quite as easy to move stuff about as it is with Java (although it is better than it used to be).

Also, does it have to be desktop - I would seriously consider (a properly architected) rowser based desktop application.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse RCP works. The result is decent on Windows and acceptable on Mac. It tends to be sluggish on Mac because of the high memory requirements though.

Answer (score 0):

C# with Framework .Net can be good not only for Windows but for [Linux with Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).

Microsoft have a [CLI that work on MAC  OSX10.2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=3a1c93fa-7462-47d0-8e56-8dd34c6292f0&displaylang=en).

Comment: The question just got edited for Mac too. Humm I have found a CLI for MAC here http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=3a1c93fa-7462-47d0-8e56-8dd34c6292f0&displaylang=en