# Which lang to focus on cross-platform?

Tags: programming-languages, cross-platform

Lets say you r going to develop a photo editng software for win, linux and mac os. What language-gui woild you choose?

Dont tell me java because i dont like swing at all.

Thanks

Comment: Probably a duplicate, definitely a poorly written and thought out question.

Comment: Sorry i am not english. Which errors i did?

Comment: U R not English? Y did U Uz chat spEk lIk "you r going to"? (Sorry I couldn't resist, but the point being that you should avoid things like nonstandard contractions, and proofread the question.)

Comment: Java/Swing, Python/TK, TCL/TK, C/GTK, C++/QT, etc. I would pick a language first and then see what UI libraries exist for it. If the available UI libraries are not sufficient, pick the next-best language and try again.

Comment: Definitely something we've seen before, and the current two answer were in most (probably all) the other ones. I'll see what I can find. [Good language & framework for cross platform (windows & mac) desktop application.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/189140/2509), [Preferred development platform for cross-platform desktop GUI?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/402688/2509) and in general http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cross-platform .

Answer (score 3):

You should give QT of Trolltech a try, its a C++ framework which you can use
to develop nice GUI applications on almost any platform

[QT Website](http://qt.nokia.com/products/)

Comment: Wow pretty nice. Only thing that scares me is that it powered by nokia

Comment: Nokia just bought it, it doessn't change the framework itself, it used to be owned by trolltech, the other thing you could do is write low level C++ code that runs on any platform, to do the calculations. Then you should write a GUI layer that uses the low level code to do the things with mouse clicks etc... but this is a lot more work than just using something like QT

Comment: +1 Qt is the best GUI framework I have ever used.

Answer (score 0):

There's a cross-platform GUI toolkit called wxWidgets. It's a C++ library, but it has binding for Python, and possibly other languages as well. It works on all of the operating systems you've mentioned. I've used it successfully in the past, although it has been a while.

http://www.wxwidgets.org/